# Unattended-upgrade --- update everything out of everytihng silently without any barriers

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, automation, unattended-upgrades

I installed *unattended-upgrade* via `apt-get installl unattended-upgrade`, then came to configure it with `dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrade`.

I then came into the following screen with the saying:

> Please specify a value for the unattended-upgrade origins-pattern

[image]

What should be answered there if one wants to give 100% credibility to `unattended-upgrade`, that is, allow it to always upgrade everything out of everything that **it can indeed** upgrade--- I don't want to specify anything specific, I just want everything to be upgraded and updated always, or at least in the possible maximum. Without barriers.

**What value is good for that, if at all?**

- I executed `man unattended-upgrade` but found no information about that.
- A glimpse via `nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrade` doesn't bring up any "didactic data" I could recognize to determine what's the best option for me.
- I didn't find any StackExchange session on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `unattended-upgrades` isn't the right way to go here. This cronjob is a simpler approach:

```
crontab -e
```

Then add the cronjob:

```
0 0 * * 0 apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get update -y
```

### Note:

The system I upgrade and update this way is a WSL Ubuntu without much data. Generally I have no problem to uninstall and resintall it as much as I like.

Of course, the approach I've taken should always be took with caution.

Answer (score 1):

An `Origins-Pattern` of `origin=*` will match all configured sources.

Note however, that this doesn't guarentee that absolutely everything will always be up to date:

- Packages may be excluded by `Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist`, by apt pinning preferences, or by dpkg holds.
- Packages where configuration files have been changed may require human intervention, depending on `Dpkg::Options`.
- Software may require a reboot. See also `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot`.
- Sources may update to have conflicting packages, which cannot be installed together.

Comment: Does this get everything? Also this seems to be the format stackoverflow prescribes so I can't do anything about it.
`APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";  APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";  Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {  "origin=*";  };  Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages "true";  Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";  Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";  Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "+1";`